# How to change default action when running a .sh file?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, scripts

Every time I want to run a .sh file, Ubuntu asks whether I want to Run in Terminal/Display/Run it. Is there a way to set default action for some sh files?

-- I am using Ubuntu 12.04 without any special changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making each `.desktop` files for **Run in Terminal** or **Display** or **Run** ,  you can set default action for each sh files.

Execute authority is given to each .desktop files.

### For example:

- **Run in terminal**

Filename : **sample-term.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Run in terminal
Exec='/fullpath_to_script/sample1.sh'
Terminal=true
```

Click this file, it will be able to run sample1.sh in terminal.

- **Display**

Filename : **sample-edit.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Edit script
Exec=gedit '/fullpath_to_script/sample2.sh'
Terminal=false
```

Click this file, it will be able to edit sample2.sh by `gedit`.

- **Run**

Filename : **sample-run.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Run script
Exec='/fullpath_to_script/sample3.sh'
Terminal=false
```

Click this file, it will be able to run sample3.sh.

Answer (score 22):

Open Nautilus, then go to Edit -> Preferences. Open `Behavior` tab and you'll find the options to set the file manager behavior when you open executable text files.

Comment: well, isn't there a way to specify it only for some files? An option like: `remember action for this file`?

Comment: I don't think so.